# How to load .txt files in python for loop?

Tags: python

I have 10 data in txt format: a1.txt,a2.txt,...,a10.txt and I want to load them one by one in a for loop.

To load a file I use

```
data = read_data('a1.txt');
```

but I am not sure how to use it in a for loop.

Comment: Start by asking yourself, what part should change on each iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 2):

Search for files inside path that end with .txt

```py
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath='/tmp'

files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f)) and f.endswith('.txt')]
```

Another approach with [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib#module-pathlib) (python 3.4+). It recognizes also the a for matching:

```py
from pathlib import Path

files = [str(f) for f in Path(mypath).iterdir() if f.match("a*.txt")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `range()` function to generate a sequence of numbers, and then use string formatting to assemble the filename:

```
for number in range(1, 11):
    filename = 'a%d.txt' % number
    data = read_data(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the txt files in a folder you could read the entire folder and loop through the txt files in it.

```
   import glob 
   folder_path = 'path/to/the/folder'

   for filename in glob.glob(folder_path, '*.txt')):
       #Your process for each file
```